# How to get the contents of API using Java?

Tags: java, api

I want to get the values of a weather api from

http://www.dataweave.in/apis/usage/13/Indian-Weather-Data

Like in **PHP**, the syntax to get the values from the api is:

```
$String=file_get_contents("url of the api");
```

But i would like to do the same in java. How can i get the file contents from the api in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://api.dataweave.in/v1/indian_weather/findByCity/?api_key=b20a79e582ee4953ceccf41ac28aa08d&city=Agartala&date=20120501");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

`inputLine` has your data.

Comment: Do you know how to fetch individual values from the String named "inputLine" in which the whole content of the file is stored and print them individually?

Comment: The string returned is in jsonformat. Get a JSONObject from the string with `new JSONObject(inputLine)` and then parse the values you need. You can also use libraries like gson.

Comment: But it gives me an error "String can not be converted into Map"

Comment: can you provide the code you're trying to do. It should be `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputLine);`

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the code...like i have written: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(inputLine);